# PHP served video display on Apple products

Tags: php, ios, iphone, html

I'm trying to show a video on my Mac and I phone but I can't get it to work.  My videos are served by php, I've been reading it has to do with range headers not being sent but I can't figure out how to do it correctly. 
Heres what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<video controls="true" autoplay muted loop> 
<source src="http://my_site.com/video/394934" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

PHP:

```
// Get file GUID
$file_guid = (int) get_input('file_guid', 0);

// Get file thumbnail size
$size = get_input('size', 'small');

$file = get_entity($file_guid);
if (!elgg_instanceof($file, 'object', 'file')) {
    exit;
}

$simpletype = $file->simpletype;
if ($simpletype == "image") {

// Get file thumbnail
switch ($size) {
    case "small":
        $thumbfile = $file->thumbnail;
        break;
    case "medium":
        $thumbfile = $file->smallthumb;
        break;
    case "large":
    default:
        $thumbfile = $file->largethumb;
        break;
}

// Grab the file
if ($thumbfile && !empty($thumbfile)) {
    $readfile = new ElggFile();
    $readfile->owner_guid = $file->owner_guid;
    $readfile->setFilename($thumbfile);
    $mime = $file->getMimeType();
    $contents = $readfile->grabFile();

    // caching images for 10 days
    header("Content-type: $mime");
    header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', strtotime("+10 days")), true);
    header("Pragma: public", true);
    header("Cache-Control: public", true);
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($contents));

    echo $contents;
    exit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it is in fact a range headers issue, there's a github project with a code example tackling this issue for Safari/Mac:

https://gist.github.com/codler/3906826